# ubuntu and LAMP security precautions for newbies

Tags: linux, windows-10, ubuntu, security

Currently I am a Windows user and I use WAMP. I have a new project with very sensitive information, security is extremely critical. I will carry private keys of my clients for external services. I will need to run each week a php script that will make curl connection to these services through REST api and make some updates.

I will run the php script on localhost through browser (localhost/projectname/run.php), but external world should not have access.

What I need:

1. LAMP to run php script.
2. Nautilus to copy files from external server and upload it back.
3. Chrome browser to access gmail, amazon aws etc.
4. Possibly a simple IDE.

I will buy a new laptop with freedos where I will install ubundu and the above apps. The laptop will be online only when I will run the script for better security.

Are there any security precautions I need to take with ubundu such as firewall and other? I am not a linux user but I know how to install simple things like LAMP through tutorial. But I am worried if there are some things that I may not be aware as linux newbie.

Does default ubundu installation provide enough security or do I need further tuning? And in such case maybe it will be more secure if I just install Windows 10, WAMP, Winscp and Notepad++?